# Sqlite Query - Test for existence of multiple values across set area of database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to search a bible table that has book, chapter, verse, content. What I am looking to see is does one chapter contain ALL of a set of search terms, and return the book and chapter where these terms exist at least once.

I have tried:

```
select book, chapter, content from bible 
where content like '%Joseph%' AND content like '%prison%'
Group by book, chapter
```

This returns a match for a given verse but i would like to match even if one word is in verse 1 and another is in verse N in the same book/chapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation based conditions:

```
select book, chapter
from bible
Group by book, chapter
having count(case when content like '%Joseph%' then 1 end) > 0
AND count(case when content like '%prison%' then 1 end) > 0;
```